# How would I go about traversing this JSON object?

Tags: php, json, object

How would I access the [0] -> Array() located below and retrieve the [title] which is "Spirited Away" by iterating over the array?

```
Array
(
     [@attributes] => Array
    (
        [version] => 2.0
    )

[channel] => Array
    (
        [title] => Site Title
        [link] => site/
        [language] => en-us
        [category] => All
        [image] => Array
            (
                [title] => Site
                [url] => http://example.com
                [link] => example.com
            )

        [item] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [title] => Spirited Away
                        [pubDate] => date
                        [category] => Movies
                        [link] => linkhere
                        [enclosure] => Array
                            (
                                [@attributes] => Array
                                    (
                                        [url] => someurlhere
                                        [length] => length
                                        [type] => application/x-bittorrent
                                    )

                            )
```

I'm currently trying to iterate over the array using a foreach loop but It's outputting nothing. I would post my code but the code section of this question is already too long. I'm using PHP and nothing I have tried so far was working.

This JSON code was generated from an XML document using json_encode and then decoded using json_decode into a JSON object.

Comment: `echo $array['channel']['item'][0]['title'];`

Comment: `foreach ( $array['channel']['item'] as $x){echo $x['title'];)`

Comment: Its always a good idea to add the JSON String to your question. Then people can actually build a test of their answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

comment to answer as its correct.

to loop through this particular array structure its:

```
foreach ( $array['channel']['item'] as $x){
    echo $x['title'];
}
```